# Exclude the beginning from the regex

Tags: regex

I need regular expression which from something like this:

```
<li><a href="/wiki/%E1%83%90%E1%83%90%E1%83%92%E1%83%94%E1%83%91%E1%83%A1" title="ააგებს">ააგებს</a></li>
```

Will match:

```
%E1%83%90%E1%83%90%E1%83%92%E1%83%94%E1%83%91%E1%83%A1
```

So far I got:

```
<li><a href="/wiki/%.*\d
```

But I don't know how to exclude the beginning from the result. Any ideas? I'm using Python.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what flavor of regex, so best-guess:

```
/href="\/wiki\/((?:%[a-f0-9]{2})+)"/ig
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a .NET language then you could do that more robustly than just using a regex to try to get the value. The HtmlAgilityPack is good for parsing HTML, even if the HTML is a bit malformed.

Here I have a function which tries to extract the href attribute of the first  element in a piece of HTML, and then the rest of the program shows two ways you might extract the part of the href after "/wiki/":

```
Option Infer On

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Module Module1

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Get the value of the href attribute in the first anchor (&lt;a>) element of (a fragment of) an HTML string.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="s">An HTML fragment.</param>
    ''' <returns>The value of the href attribute in the first anchor (&lt;a>) element.</returns>
    ''' <remarks>Throws a FormatException if the href value cannot be found.</remarks>
    Function GetHref(s As String) As String
        ' Get the value of the href attribute, if it exists, in a reliable fashion. '
        Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlDocument
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(s)
        Dim link = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a")
        Dim hrefValue = String.Empty

        If link IsNot Nothing Then
            If link.Attributes("href") IsNot Nothing Then
                hrefValue = link.Attributes("href").Value
            Else
                ' there was no href '
                Throw New FormatException("No href attribute in the <a> element.")
            End If
        Else
            ' there was no <a> element '
            Throw New FormatException("No <a> element.")
        End If

        Return hrefValue

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim s = "<li><a href=""/wiki/%E1%83%90%E1%83%90%E1%83%92%E1%83%94%E1%83%91%E1%83%A1"" title=""ააგებს"">ააგებს</a></li>"

        Dim dataToCapture = String.Empty

        Dim hrefValue = GetHref(s)

        ' OPTION 1 - using RegEx
        ' Only get a specific pattern of characters
        Dim re = New Regex("^/wiki/((?:%[0-9A-F]{2})+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Dim m = re.Match(hrefValue)

        If m.Success Then
            dataToCapture = m.Groups(1).Value
            Console.WriteLine(dataToCapture)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to match with RegEx.")
        End If

        ' OPTION 2 - looking at the string
        ' Just get whatever comes after the required start of the href value.
        Dim mustStartWith = "/wiki/"
        If hrefValue.StartsWith(mustStartWith) Then
            dataToCapture = hrefValue.Substring(mustStartWith.Length)
            Console.WriteLine(dataToCapture)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Nothing found with string operations.")
        End If

        ' the percent-encoded data could be decoded with System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(dataToCapture) '

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

In a regex, parentheses, i.e. `( )`, indicate a group to capture. However, we don't need to capture the individual `%AA` parts, so those have a `?:` modifier to indicate that they are *non-capturing* groups.

(The spurious 's are only to help SO colour the code properly.)

Comment: The OP has since revealed that they are using Python 2.7, but I will leave this here in the hope someone finds it useful. Unless there are objections.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are using Python, you can use something like [Python Regular Expression Testing Tool](http://www.pythonregex.com/):

```
>>> regex = re.compile("href=\"/wiki/((?:%[0-9A-F]{2})+)\"",re.IGNORECASE)
>>> r = regex.search(string)
>>> r
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xd640db26af2f1d60>
>>> regex.match(string)
None

# List the groups found
>>> r.groups()
(u'%E1%83%90%E1%83%90%E1%83%92%E1%83%94%E1%83%91%E1%83%A1',)

# List the named dictionary objects found
>>> r.groupdict()
{}

# Run findall
>>> regex.findall(string)
[u'%E1%83%90%E1%83%90%E1%83%92%E1%83%94%E1%83%91%E1%83%A1']
```

where `string` is set to your example data.

However, similarly to what I showed for .NET, it would probably be better to parse the HTML with something like [BeatifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to get the value of the href and then work on that.